# Displaying newline character in PDF generated with FOP

Tags: xml, pdf-generation, apache-fop

I'm generating a PDF document using FOP. The source XML contains some text data which contains  newlines. But when its being shown in PDF, all new lines are converted into spaces. I tried replacing all \n characters with

```
&#xA;
```

in the java code but that is not helping too. How can I display the new lines in PDF document?
Can you please provide your suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

oopsie...figured it out..

```
linefeed-treatment="preserve"
```

Should be added to fo:block...thats all